# What is the purpose of the PropertySpecified pattern used by XML Serialization?

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, xml-serialization

What is the purpose of the PropertySpecified pattern used by XML Serialization ?
What problem does it tryto solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tries to solve the problem that `int` `float` and so on cannot be null, so it has no other way to signal whether the attribute/element exists in the XML file or not.

It was really only useful in .NET 1.x, since in .NET 2 you can just use `Nullable<T>` (e.g. `int?`) instead.

Comment: read about it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx